# SVN history in OpenGrok on Windows (certificate issue)

Tags: windows-10, certificate, svn, tomcat

I do have a problem with configuring svn to work with OpenGrok (on Tomcat85) on Windows 10 as I need the svn https certificate to be added to trusted ones.

According to http://www.microhowto.info/howto/configure_subversion_to_trust_a_given_ssl_certificate.html and https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/issues/846 it seems that i need to add certificate to some config file but it needs to be added to Tomcat85 service user.

How to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution.

Tomcat as service runs as system user, therefore we need to add certificate to that user's folder.

1. Initially, as home user I have accepted to permanently trust my svn certificate
2. Then just copy matching file from *C:\Users\[username]\Application Data\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server* to *C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server*